# Trouble displaying an Image on  Watch

Tags: xcode, uiimage, watchkit

I need to display an image in a  Watch app. Initially I was using `imageView.setImageNamed("us")` and it was good.

Now I need to manipulate the image so I need to create an instance of the image, then manipulate and display it. To make an instance (a copy) of the image I use `let image = UIImage(named: "us")!` but it returns `nil` and I can't understand the reason... Does someone know why?

EDIT: [Here's an example project.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4712155/Prova.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in Assets.
If you use a unique Assets for iPhone and Watch that's how to set "Target Membership":

- Using `imageView.setImageNamed("us")`, the image is managed directly from a storyboard so you need to set the target to WatchKit App (graphic part of Watch App).
- Using `let image = UIImage(named: "us")!`, the image is managed programmatically from an interface controller so you need to set a target to WatchKit Extension (code part of Watch App).

[image]

Comment: 1) Already did it but nothing. 2) Using other string everything works so targets are correct. 3) It's a png but I'm not calling the image with extension. 4) Simulator, I'm not a Watch owner. 5) I'm using WatchKit for a watch app!

Comment: oops sorry. It's a very simple app with use only WatchKit!

Comment: I added an example project.

Comment: Great! I update the answer which, now, should be more clear.